# UrlPathEncode() alternative

Tags: c#, http, encoding, escaping

The [MSDN page for UrlPathEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode(v=vs.110).aspx) states the UrlPathEncode shouldn't be used, and that I should use UrlEncode instead.

> Do not use; intended only for browser compatibility. Use UrlEncode.

But [UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) does not do the same thing as UrlPathEncode.

My use case is that I want to encode a file system path so that a file can be downloaded. The spaces in a path need to be escaped, but not the forward slashes etc. UrlPathEncode does exactly this.

```
// given the path
string path = "Directory/Path to escape.exe";

Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(path));
// returns "Installer/My%20Installer.msi" <- This is what I require

Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path));
// returns "Installer%2fMy+Installer.msi"

// none of these return what I require, either
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path, Encoding.ASCII));
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode));
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path, Encoding.Default));
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path, Encoding.UTF32));
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path, Encoding.UTF7));
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path, Encoding.UTF8));
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(path, Encoding.Unicode));
```

Another method I've tried is using Uri.EscapeDataString, but this escapes the slashes.

```
// returns Directory%2FPath%20to%20escape.exe
Console.WriteLine(Uri.EscapeDataString(path));
```

### Question:

If I'm not *supposed* to use UrlPathEncode, and UrlEncode doesn't produce the required output, what method is equivalent and recommended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's funny that when trying to write a question properly, you find your answer:

```cs
Uri.EscapeUriString(path);
```

Produces the required output.

I do think the MSDN page should reflect this, though.

**Edit (2020-11-22)**

I've recently come across this again, but needing to URL encode URLs with special characters (instead of file names with spaces), but it's essentially the same thing. The approach I used this time was to instantiate the Uri class:

```cs
var urlWithSpecialChars = "https://www.example.net/something/contàins-spécial-chars?query-has=spécial-chars-as-well";

var uri = new Uri(urlWithSpecialChars);

// outputs "https://www.example.net/something/contàins-spécial-chars?query-has=spécial-chars-as-well"
Debug.WriteLine(uri.OriginalString);

// outputs "https://www.example.net/something/cont%C3%A0ins-sp%C3%A9cial-chars?query-has=sp%C3%A9cial-chars-as-well"
Debug.WriteLine(uri.AbsoluteUri);

// outputs "/something/cont%C3%A0ins-sp%C3%A9cial-chars?query-has=sp%C3%A9cial-chars-as-well"
Debug.WriteLine(uri.PathAndQuery);
```

This give you quite a bit of useful Uri properties that are likely to cover most/many Uri processing requirements:
[image]